# Currency converting issue I am facing now

Tags: python

I was trying to print the output under the 2nd `for` loop (enter the amount Of $20: ...), but I am getting 0. How to fix this issue? The user gets amount of $20 : 1, and amount of $2.00: 2, when they input 22 from keyboard.

Code:

```
denomitions={"$20.00":0,
             "$10.00":0,
             "$5.00":0,
             "$2.00":0,
             "$1.00":0,
             "$0.25":0,
             "0.10":0,
             "0.5":0}

 dividers = [2000,1000,500,200,100,25,10,5]

 number = float(input("please enter the amount for change:").strip("$"))
 #convert dollar to cents
 change = int(number*100)

 for i in range(len(denomitions)):

     amount = int(change/dividers[i])

     change= change- amount * dividers[i]

     #print the result out
     index= float(dividers[i] / 100.00)
     print(index,":",amount)

 #print the result out
 for k in denomitions:
     print("amount of "+str(k),amount)
```

Comment: Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question. Copy paste the code and format them as code. check: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
denomitions={"$20.00":0,
             "$10.00":0,
             "$5.00":0,
             "$2.00":0,
             "$1.00":0,
             "$0.25":0,
             "0.10":0,
             "0.5":0}

dividers = [2000,1000,500,200,100,25,10,5]
#add an empty list
amount_list = []

number = float(input("please enter the amount for change:").strip("$"))

#convert dollar to cents
change = int(number*100)
    
for i in range(len(denomitions)):
        
    amount = int(change/dividers[i])
        
    change= change- amount * dividers[i]
        
    #print the result out
    index= float(dividers[i] / 100.00)
    print(index,":",amount)
    
    #fill the list with the amount at index i
    amount_list.append(amount)
    #print the result out

i = 0
for k in denomitions:
    #now you can retrieve the amount from the list if you keep the same index
    print("amount of "+str(k), str(amount_list[i]))
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the second for loop, it picks up the amount equal to the last round of the previous for loop. At the end of the first loop amount = 0, therefore you will always get zero when printing amount in the second for loop.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for replying. How to fix this issue so that I don’t get zero ?